# Create a datetime with a time span of 24/7 (repeat every day)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, nopcommerce

Iv'e made a List Method that gets total amount of sold products in my MVC/ASP.NET application. I need to ad a DateTime parameter to the List Method that tells it to only get sold products of the day before.

The purpose of this list is that the client can see what he have sold previous day and the quantity of the sold products. This is just some sales statistics.

I'm not sure how to create a timespan for the method to get the items from. I was thinking about using datetime as a parameter to the List Method and then declair the timespan. I'm not sure how to approach this though..

This is my IList Method:

```
public IList<BestsellersReportLine> DailyBestSellersReport(int billingCountryId = 0,
            int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1, bool showHidden = false)
        {


                var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                         join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                         join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                         join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                         select opv;


                var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
                    //group by product variants
                       from opv in query1
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       :
                    //group by products
                       from opv in query1
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       ;

                switch (orderBy)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
                }

                if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
                    query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

                var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
                {
                    var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
                    {
                        EntityId = x.EntityId,
                        TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                        TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
                    };
                    return reportLine;
                }).ToList();

                return result;

        }
```

Ive created these variables to work with, dunno if this is right?:

```
        DateTime CurrentDay = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime PreviousDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        DateTime TimeFrame = DateTime.Parse("00:00:00 AM");
```

Anny ideas?

Thank you!

//Chris

Comment: Where do you want to use the TimeSpan?

Comment: Hejsan! I would like the method get the items "within" a timespan. This is going to be a Scheduled Task running in the background and it needs to be executed at the end of each day. So if the method was executed this day (after 00:00am 2014-01-24) it would get all products sold yesterday (2014-01-24) between 00:00am - 00:00am. Then repeat this process every day. Hope this makes sence

Comment: Ok, you could use DateTime.Now and create a new DateTime using the year, month and day from the DateTime.Now call to get a DateTime with 00:00am in. Then use DateTime.AddDays(-1) to get a second date and use these days to compare with. Alternatively, create a TimeSpan using this technique. If this is what you're asking for, I could try to formulate an answer.

Comment: Yep that's it. Datetime.now is probably ideal in this context as it needs to originate from something. I was thinking about AddDays to but i'm not exactly sure how to write the code for this, haven't used datetime in a context like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.Subtract( new TimeSpan( 1, 0, 0, 0 ) );
var earliest = new DateTime( yesterday.Year, yesterday.Month, yesterday.Day, 0, 0, 0 );
var latest = earliest.Add( new TimeSpan( 1, 0, 0, 0, -1 ) );
```

Usage;

```
where earliest <= dateToTest && latest >= dateToTest
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! What exactly does the number represent within the "( )" in "yesterday" and "latest = earliest". I suspect "1" is for day but there are 4 digits. You are not using a spicific time?

Comment: Timespan( days, hours, minutes, seconds, [milliseconds] ), so the last usage to calcuate `latest` adds 1 day but subtracts 1 milliseconds, which will give you the last millisecond of that day

Comment: I see thanks. And "<= dateToTest && latest >= dateToTest" is representing  "<= Today && latest >= yesterday" ? I used DateTime.Now for today and DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) for yesterday. I shouldn't set the date as the process is suposed to repeat every day and not a specific day

Comment: dateToTest would be the property of the entities that is the `DateTime` you want to fall within the calculated date range

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
 var range = new
        {
            Start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
            End = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(-1)
        };
```

and use it like,

```
(DateOfSale>=range.Start && DateOfSale<=range.End)
```

Comment: This might work for me. I have StarTime and EndTime variables from the database but i'm not sure what to replace "DateOfSale" with. Can i replace DateOfSale with DateTime.now.addDays(-1) as i wan't to test yesterdays date? Thank you!

Comment: @KristofferAndersson `DateOfSale` is the column name (or property name ) which contains the date to test against.

Comment: Ok can i set Start as DateOfSale as its AddDays(-1) representing yesterday?

Comment: In my above answer, the `range.Start` holds the yesterday's date at `12.00 am` at the beginning of the day and `range.End` holds yesterday's date at `11:59PM` at the end of the day. This is necessary if you want to test date including time information.

Comment: Oh im sorry, my question was badly formulated. There's only 2 dates i need. Today and yesterday, allthough i can't specify a certain date like for ex: 2014-01-31 -because this function is ment to repeat everyday. What i want to test is what products have been sold between startDate and endDate (today and yesterday). Do i need a 3rd DateTime to calculate the time inbetween startDate and endDate? I have this dates from the database: startTimeUtc, endTimeUtc and CreatedOnUtc. Thank you

Comment: Where do you store the date of a product was sold? In your question, I don't see any date property being used from any of the entities referenced in query.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you can calculate Date at 12.00 AM and then continue operation as,

```
   DateTime Today12AMDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
   DateTime PreviousDay12AMDate = Today12AMDate.AddDays(-1);
```

Your condition will look like,

```
where dateFromDatabase <= Today12AMDate && dateFromDatabase >= PreviousDay12AMDate
```